# How to stop the iframes from blinking?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a html page in which i have a **div**. Inside the div there is an **iframe**,

```
<div id="div1">
<iframe id="biframe" src="" allowtransparency="true" application="yes" >
</iframe>
</div>
```

In javascript function I'm changing the src of the iframe dynamically.

```
 window.frames['biframe'].document.location.href="105.htm";
 $('div1').style.display="block";
```

The above 2 lines will be called in a button click, the div will be displayed and the iframe will be loaded.

**Problem :** When the button is clicked the iframe blinks before getting displayed properly. The flash occurs for a very short time, but very irritating when I'm going to display different source in each button click. For now I have 5 buttons.

**Solution Tried :** I tried with the below solution given in some forum,

```
<iframe src="..." style="visibility:hidden;" onload="this.style.visibility='visible';"></iframe>
```

...but didn't work.

Please suggest a good solution to end this problem.

Note : JQuery/any JS library cant be used in this page (I'm not allowed to).

Comment: You'll have to re-set `visibility` to hidden before you assign a new url to it. Also, why are you modifying the iframe's location object? Just change the `src` of the iframe should work.

Comment: @Passerby Thank you!! I got it right. Now I understand how the trick works and have answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Paul Irish and his Surefire DOM Element Insertion and Ryan Seddon and his article on inserting scoped style elements, we have this:

```
// Prevent variables from being global      
(function () {

      /*
          1. Inject CSS which makes iframe invisible
      */

    var div = document.createElement('div'),
        ref = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0] || 
              document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    div.innerHTML = '&shy;<style> iframe { visibility: hidden; } </style>';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(div, ref);


    /*
        2. When window loads, remove that CSS, 
           making iframe visible again
    */

    window.onload = function() {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }

})();
```

Just include that on any page (in the `<head>`) with the white flash problem and it will be solved. Just note that we're using window.onload here, so if your page also uses that somewhere, combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Initially in the **body** part I set the iframe's visibility to hidden (unnecessary). Later in the button click function I maintained the visibility hidden, and changed the src attribute dynamically.

I created another function to make the iframe visible and called that function in the onload event of the iframe.

And it worked!!

The sample code is as follows,

```
<div id="Bframe">
<iframe id="biframe" style="visibility:hidden;" src="" allowtransparency="true" application="yes" onload="showiframe()">
</iframe>
</div>
```

...called the below lines in the button click event,

```
$('biframe').style.visibility="hidden";
window.frames['biframe'].document.location.href="105.htm";
$('Bframe').style.display="block";
```

...And the below function will be called later,

```
function showiframe()
{
    $('biframe').style.visibility="visible";
}
```

**What is happening?**

When I click the button, my iframe will get hidden. I will assign the **src** attribute.
My iframe load event will get called after iframe is loaded which will show the iframe.
That means iframe will be hidden in its loading period, avoiding white flash.