# Update field with CherryPy

Tags: html, cherrypy

I'm pretty new to web development so please bear with me. I have a control webpage (run by `cherrypy`) with status values representing a python process running serverside. How can I update or push the new values?

The only way I would now how would be with something like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

which updates the entire page. I would however prefer with only needed fields gets updated. Is this easily possible with pure `html` respectively directly by `cherrypy`?

Comment: you could open a *websocket* and talk to your backend over it. Or ask over ajax, but that's clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal way is using javascript/websockets/ajax.

But given the constraints of "server side only". I believe you can accomplish that
with iframes.

```
import  cherrypy as cp

MAIN_PAGE = """
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> Im the main page! </h1>
    <iframe frameBorder="0"  src="/frame"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
"""

FRAME_PAGE = """
<html>
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
  </head>
  <body>
     Counter: <strong>{}</strong>
  </body>
</html>
"""

class Root:

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    @cp.expose
    def default(self):
        return MAIN_PAGE

    @cp.expose
    def frame(self):
        self.counter += 1
        return FRAME_PAGE.format(self.counter)

cp.quickstart(Root())
```

Which is indeed reloading a full page, but just within the frame. To avoid the blinking on the iframe, you will need some [javascript/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396885/how-to-stop-the-iframes-from-blinking).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not thinking about frames. How does this solution affect traffic? I plan to have something like 20 fields which should update asynchronosly.

Comment: This is not the most efficient way of doing the thing, but I believe is the only way if you just want to use python on the server. As I mentioned you have to use javascript in order to do "the right way". 1. Websockets or 2. Ajax polling. And about the cost, you will have a lot of requests, with this and the ajax solution.

Comment: Okey. I'll try it this way then. Thank you for the clarification.